# Why doesn't std::unique_ptr have an aliasing constructor like std::shared_ptr has?

Tags: c++, c++11

I've just discovered `std::shared_ptr`'s "aliasing constructor" and find myself asking "why doesn't std::unique_ptr have an corresponding one?

That is, if you want to allocate a `Foo` so that you can pass its `Bar` member to a function that should entirely manage the lifetime of the `Foo`, wouldn't it be nice to be able to do so?

```
#include <memory>

struct B {}
struct A {
  B b;
}

void f(std::unique_ptr<B> b);

std::unique_ptr<A> a = std::make_unique<A>();
std::unique_ptr<B> b { std::move(a), &(a->b) };  // a now invalid.
f(std::move(b));  // f now responsible for deleting the A.
```

This works with std::shared_ptr ( http://ideone.com/pDK1bc )

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

struct B {
  std::string s;
};
struct A {
  B b;
  A(std::string s) : b{s} {};
  ~A() { std::cout << "A deleted." << std::endl; }
};

void f(std::shared_ptr<B> b) {
  std::cout << "in f, b->s = " << b->s << " (use_count=" << b.use_count() << ")" << std::endl;
}

int main() {
  std::shared_ptr<A> a = std::make_shared<A>("hello");
  std::shared_ptr<B> b { a, &(a->b) };
  a.reset();  // a now invalid.
  std::cout << "before f, b->s = " << b->s << " (use_count=" << b.use_count() << ")" << std::endl;
  f(std::move(b));  // f now responsible for deleting the A.
  std::cout << "after f" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

outputs the expected

```
before f, b->s = hello (use_count=1)
in f, b->s = hello (use_count=1)
A deleted.
after f
```

Is there a logical reason why such a thing wasn't included? And/or, is it a bad idea to emulate it with a `unique_ptr<B>` with a custom deleter that deletes the `A`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe the “problem” is that, unlike `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`'s deleter is not type-erased. The default deleter of `std::unique_ptr<T>` (which has zero size, encoded into the type itself as a barely visible default type parameter) is simply `[](T * p){ delete p; }`. But it is clear that a `std::unique_ptr<B>` that was created via `std::make_unique<B>` and one that was made by pointing to a `B` member of an `A` object cannot have the same deleter. The deleter for the latter case would have to do some pointer arithmetic to obtain the original `A *` pointer back. Those two deleters could only have the same type if both would store an offset or an internal pointer to the original object. And that would no longer have zero size. `std::unique_ptr` was designed to have zero overhead compared to doing `new` and `delete` manually, which is a Good Thing. I don't see any immediate drawbacks from using your own deleters that store that additional pointer, though I'd still have to come across a use-case where I'd find this useful.

Answer (score 7):

`shared_ptr` has reference counting overhead.  In its reference counting block it also stores an explicit deleter (because if you are storing on the heap, what is a few more bytes?)

This is also why a `shared_ptr` to a base type can remember to delete derived types without a virtual dtor.

`unique_ptr`, on the other hand, stores its deleter in the instance, and the default deleter is stateless -- 0 bytes used.  This makes `unique_ptr` zero overhead over a raw pointer in terms of memory usage.

A stateless deleter cannot remember to delete something else.

You can add a stateful deleter to `unique_ptr` that supports aliasing, but then you'll have to alias manually.  One of the constructors takes both a pointer and a deleter.

Comment: And then since the deleter's part of the type, it doesn't interop well with plain `unique_ptr<T>` unless you type erase the deleter, which is even more extra overhead.

Comment: @T.C.: Even if you type erase the deleter, it doesn't interop well with `unique_ptr<T, default_deleter<T>>`.  At least, conversion is possible in one direction only.

Comment: @ben in theory both ways, so long as failure is allowed.